# WPF Window unresponsive during long-running command

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

I didn't think this actually happened, but it appears that my WPF app (window) is not calling a Sub asynchronously, or something that looks like this... The use case is deceivingly simple:

**wpfw** = WPF Window

**StatusLeft** = textbox on wpfw

**cmds** = Command class instantiated in wpfw class to store all window commands (subs). the 
wpfw instance is passed to it in the constructor.

**UpdateStatusLeft** = a Sub in cmds that looks like this:

```
Private Sub UpdateStatusLeft(UpdateText As String)
    Try
        Me.wpfw.Dispatcher.Invoke(CType(Sub() Me.wpfw.StatusLeft.Text = UpdateText, Action))
    Catch ex As Exception
        [...]
    End Try
End Sub
```

The above works, but only updates the main window after the long running sub in cmds is finished. Calling that long running command is nothing special:

```
(XAML)
 <MenuItem Header="Process Files" Click="mnuReference_ProcessFiles"/>
```

in wpfw, the handler for the click (*mnuReference_ProcessFiles*) is this:

```
Private Sub mnuReference_ProcessFiles(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.cmds.ParseFiles()
End Sub
```

Now cmds is instantiated as soon as the wpfw is, and the sub it is pointing to (*mnuReference_ProcessFiles*) looks like this:

```
Public Sub ParseFiles() Implements Icmds.ParseFiles
    Try
        Dim fu As FileUtils = New FileUtils()
        Me.UpdateStatusLeft("Starting Batch 1...")
        ipu.ParseFile(".\batch1")
        Me.UpdateStatusLeft("Starting Batch 2...")
        ipu.ParseFile(".\batch2")
[...]
```

Above, "*Me.UpdateStatusLeft*" is in the cmds class. In fact, I put a Sub UpdateStatusLeft in every class the mainwindow calls (including it's own class!), and I pass down the wpfc *instance* to each command/processing class.

If you try to update the textarea directly frm another thread/class other than the wpfw one, you get a thread error-which is why I use *Dispatcher.Invoke(...*

Clarity:

*The commands are all firing off as expected, and do their job well.* That never was an issue.

The issue is trying to find a way to update the top/originating UI thread's textarea as those tasks progress so the user doesn't fall asleep or think the program has crashed, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The main application dispatcher uses the UI thread, so long-running processes will still lock up the UI thread

The typical solution is to run long-running processes in a background thread, then use the dispatcher to update your UI objects on the main thread once it's finished.

Or if you use something like the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx), it allows you to schedule your task for UI thread, and bypass the dispatcher completely. Here's an example:

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() => 
    {
        // This runs in a background thread
        return GetLongRunningProcessResults();
    })
    .ContinueWith.StartNew((t) => 
    {
        // This runs in the UI thread because of the
        // TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext parameter
        UpdateUI(t.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: The `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` trick is pretty neat.

Comment: @georgiosd I believe [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSyncronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) means that it will create the new `Task` using the current [SyncronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code in `ParseFiles` in a call to [Tasks.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want your application to stay responsive, you must execute intensive tasks in another thread than the main thread.